# MATLAB loop over unique function output

Tags: matlab, matrix, unique

following problem:

I have a very large matrix and several rows share the same identifier in column 1. For these rows I need to do some averaging, reformatting etc.

Currently I am identifying all unique identifier values in column 1 by using the function unique and then do averaging, reformatting of values in other columns within this loop for each set of rows sharing the same column 1 value within a loop.

```
ID = unique(data.1);
 for i = 1:length(ID);
   do stuff
 end
```

I guess this is highly inefficient and slow but I cannot think of a better way of handling this.

Comment: "*I guess this is highly inefficien*" - can you quantify that? What is it that you have in mind? This sounds a lot like an [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I need to subselect rows of a matrix, do computations between these rows, and then move on to the next set of rows.

Each batch of to be processed rows shares a common ID. 

--> So I loop over the output of the unique function which is very slow, maybe there is a vectorized approach I could attempt.

Comment: List out all the *computations* that you intend to perform. Use a minimal sample input data and maybe use one of those operations and explain to us on what must be the expected output. If possible, share your *not-vectorized* codes.

Comment: @user255715 som ethings can be vectorized, some not. If we dont know what you can do we can not vectorize it. Its like asking the question "should I put salt in the food?". Well, if its pasta yes, but dont salten your apple.

Comment: @AnderBiguri actually putting salt on an apple is quite good you should try it! :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 O.o really?

Comment: Yep that's quite good! (in my opinion haha)

Comment: do you guys like bananas?